# Prune container images with just containerd (w/o Docker)

Tags: linux, docker, containerd

If I had just `containerd` installed on a Linux system (i.e. Docker is **not** installed), how do I remove unused container images to save disk space?

Docker has that handy [`docker system prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) command, but I can't find anything similar with [`ctr`](https://github.com/projectatomic/containerd/blob/master/docs/cli.md) or 3rd party tooling.

Comment: Maybe following helps: https://gist.github.com/cirocosta/b01d9869b38e73690bb02a6371c2b221  ?

Answer (score 26):

This is probably what you want:

```
crictl rmi --prune
```